# User Provider constructor 2nd parameter

Tags: symfony, service, doctrine-orm

I have a simple custom UserProvider

```
class UserProvider extends EntityRepository implements UserProviderInterface
{
public function loadUserByUsername($username)
{
    $q = $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->where('u.username = :username OR u.email = :email')
        ->setParameter('username', $username)
        ->setParameter('email', $username)
        ->getQuery();

    try {
        $user = $q->getSingleResult();
    } catch (NoResultException $e) {
        $message = sprintf(
            'Unable to find an active admin EntUserBundle:User object identified by "%s".',
            $username
        );
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException($message, 0, $e);
    }

    return $user;
}

public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
{
    $class = get_class($user);
    if (!$this->supportsClass($class)) {
        throw new UnsupportedUserException(
            sprintf(
                'Instances of "%s" are not supported.',
                $class
            )
        );
    }

    return $this->find($user->getId());
}

public function supportsClass($class)
{
    return $this->getEntityName() === $class
        || is_subclass_of($class, $this->getEntityName());
}
}
```

And the corresponding service

```
ent.user_provider:
    class: Ent\UserBundle\Entity\UserProvider
    arguments:
        em: "@doctrine"
```

I'm having this error

```
ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 2 passed to Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata, none given
```

I know with [Symfony API](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.3/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.EntityRepository.html#60-71) that it neede 2 parameters, the 2nd being a Mapping\ClassMetadata, but what exactly am I supposed to give as parameter on the service ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

1. Create construct in your `UserProvider` class:

   ```
   use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
   use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
   ...

   class UserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
   {
       protected $em;

       public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
       {
          $this->em = $em;
       }

      public function loadUserByUsername($username)
      {
         $q = $this->em->getRepository('Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\User')->createQueryBuilder('u')
             ->where('u.username = :username OR u.email = :email')
             ->setParameter('username', $username)
             ->setParameter('email', $username)
             ->getQuery();
       ....
      }
      // other methods required by UserProviderInterface
   }
   ```
2. In services.yml do:

   ```
   ent.user_provider:
       class: Ent\UserBundle\Entity\UserProvider
       arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager"]
   ```

This was tested with Symfony 2.5.

Comment: Thanks, but what exactly are the parameters ? I've the same issue with Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager, it needs a Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata and I don't know how to give it...

Comment: try to clear cache first, because you cant get the same error as EntityManager gets diffrent params.

Comment: Yeah I forgot to clear the cache sorry, now it need a Doctrine\DBAL\Connection as first argument...

Comment: "@doctrine.connection" but extending it by ContainerAware will be faster way because you could have problems with getting second param for EntityManager.

Comment: Ok this seems to work, no more error, but $this->container is null... So i can't access to to entity manager...